# how can I linebreak javascript with regex keeping sperator

Tags: regex

what I wanna do is

change

```
1.apple2.cat3.green(1)table(2)computer①what②can i③do?●help●me●plz
```

this to

```
1.apple
2.cat
3.green
(1)table
(2)computer
①what
②can i
③do?
●help
●me
●plz
```

this

there're many kind of delimiter

"1.", "2." .. "(1)".."(2)"..■ ○

and so on

number is only a single digit
I want to list many delimiter can split or add linebreak, but keep delimiter
number or bullet should not be deleted.

Comment: Please add what you have done so far to achieve this!

Comment: Sorry, my method is too useless to add..

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex like below:

```
let s = '1.apple2.cat3.green(1)table(2)computer①what②can i③do?●help●me●plz';
let regex = /(\d\.|\(\d\)|[①-⑳]|●|■|○)[a-z]+/ig;
let result = null;
while (result = regex.exec(s)) {
   console.log(result[0]); // or you can push into an array, etc.
}
```

Comment: If blank or other characters are allowed btwn delimiters, just add them into "[a-z]"

Comment: You need a split version?

Comment: A split version:
let array = s.split(/((\d\.|\(\d\)|[①-⑳]|●|■|○)[a-z]+)/gi).filter((v, i) => i % 3 === 1);